# How to show or hide MS Teams tabs programmatically?

Tags: microsoft-teams

We're working on an app for **Microsoft Teams** where we need to make some tabs visible or not at runtime, depending on tenant and user permissions. So for example:

- Some tabs should be visible to some tenants and not to others (depending on a service call to our API's).
- Some tabs must be visible to Teams admins but not to normal users.

These are all [personal tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-personal-tab) BTW. I can't find anything in the docs that would help in this regard. Seems the tabs are fixed by the manifest and will show the same for all users.

Can this be done? how? I might settle for any feasible workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As such there no direct way to do that .

However you can have ConfigureTabs and when you add that tab to a channel [configure page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page), it will show up. You can then get the context and check what you want to do with that specific team (Maybe need to use Graph API to get more info with team Id).

This logic will run on the configuration page when the user selects to save. You can have a tab according to the logic.

```js
microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler((saveEvent) => {
    microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
        websiteUrl: "https://your-website.com",
        contentUrl: "https://your-website.com/red",
        entityId: "redIconTab",
        suggestedDisplayName: "MyNewTab"
    })
    saveEvent.notifySuccess()
})
```

This can't be done with multiple config tabs or with static tabs.
About showing tabs to some users, that is also not possible directly with the manifest.

However, you can use [`getContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/microsoftteams?view=msteams-client-js-latest#getContext__context__Context_____void_) and get the [`userObjectId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/microsoftteams.context?view=msteams-client-js-latest#userObjectId), based on which we can show a page maybe saying *"You don't have permission"*.

Comment: we only use personal tabs. I believe personal tabs cannot be added to channels. Correct? Also our tabs are static. There's one in particular meant to show reports that should not be visible to standard users, hence the question. Seems strange to me that MSFT would not think of such a use case. I hope it is in the roadmap.

Comment: For personal tabs, the content URL is set directly in your Teams app manifest by the contentUrl property in the staticTabs array. tab's content is the same for all users.
There is no show or hide MS Teams tabs functionality implement yet.

Could you please raise a user voice here:
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new

Comment: Done. Here it is, just in case anyone wants to vote it up :) https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/c5e8285d-6b74-ec11-a81b-6045bd7a8040