# How to Show or Hide a Personal Tab from respective app in Microsoft teams

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams

I have created a personal tabs from Developer protal in microsoft teams .

how to handle the tabs showing or hiding from the configuration

Scanario : I have a home page shown and whenever user completes the sso (Login) i want to show personal tabs .

I tried The configurable tabs from developer portal which didnt work out

Comment: Please include example code

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658235/how-to-show-or-hide-ms-teams-tabs-programmatically?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck